Can Frigate work with models trained on images and not videos?
I have a working Yolov8 model that detects playing cards in groups or individually. It was trained on images and I would like it to work with video clips.  I have exported it to a tflite format and it works for images but fails with video clips.  Can Frigate work with models trained on images or do I need to train a new model on video clips?
error -
 Cannot set tensor: Got value of type UINT8 but expected type FLOAT32 for input 0, name: inputs_0
repo - https://github.com/pstephenwille/frigate-rtsp
Frigate - https://docs.frigate.video
